# The variation of cache misses in GPU

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I have been toying an OpenCL kernel that access 7 global memory buffers, do something on the values and store the result back to a 8th global memory buffer. As I observed, as the input size increases, the L1 cache miss ratio (=misses(misses + hits)) varies a lot. I can't find the source of this variation. The input size here means the number of global work items (a power of 2, and a multiple of workgroup size). The number of workgroup size remains 256.

These are the results. These show the L1 cache miss ratio. Starting from 4096 work-items (16 workgroups).

```
0.677125
0.55946875
0.345994792
0.054078125
0.436167969
0.431871745
0.938546224
0.959258789
0.952941406
0.955016479
```

The profiler says it uses 18 registers per thread.
Here is the code (the function TTsum() is supposed to do just a bunch of dependent transcendent operations, so it has nothing to do with caches I guess) :

```
float TTsum(float x1, float x2, float x3, float x4, float x5, float x6, float x7)
{
        float temp = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                temp = temp +  x1 + (float)x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7;
        temp = sqrt(temp);
        temp = exp(temp);
        temp = temp / x1;
        temp = temp / (float)x2;
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) temp = sqrt(temp);
        return temp;
}

__kernel void histogram(__global float* x1,
                        __global int* x2,
                        __global float* x3,
                        __global float* x4,
                        __global float* x5,
                        __global float* x6,
                        __global float* x7,
                        __global float* y)
{
  int id = get_global_id(0);    
  for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
    y[id] = TTsum(x1[id], x2[id], x3[id], x4[id], x5[id], x6[id], x7[id]);
}
```

Can someone explain the cache behavior? The experiments are done in GTX580.

Comment: +1 looks like an epic question, nice job! :)

Comment: You should show the code to TTsum, because if its varibles are not held in register, it will also be using L2 cache.

Comment: I edited the question. Do you mean that L2 is used for register spilling? I thought it was L1? By the way all the values here are just for L1 cache only.

Comment: When variables are spilled from register, they wind up in "thread local" memory which is stored in SDRAM and read through the normal global memory L1/L2 cache structure. So cache misses can be generated by thread local memory access.

Comment: I am guessing you are using random input data. I would suggest trying the kernel without the exp and sqrt calls. Exp is a function which may well be using thread local memory and won't have a constant runtime, depending on the input. You might see something rather different if the kernel is restricted to a sequence of constant time, register based multiply-add operations.

Comment: Ok. I will try MADDs only. Are you suspecting that those transcendent functions using global memory? How could it be?

Comment: Well I removed all the exp's and sqrt's in the test, keeping only add's (the first for loop). But the cache behaviour is similar. Not only the cache misses, but also the %replays also varies a lot across the inputs.

Comment: Describe how do you perform testing in detail. Do they run as a single batch, or a separate runs?

Comment: Yes, I used a shell script to execute all the runs in one batch. Any other details do you want to know?

Comment: Weird! Are the global memory buffers distinct? Does the cache miss ratio correlate with e.g. distance(x1, x2)?

Comment: It's quite hard to calculate histograms in CUDA. I believe the random access on y[] may very well be the cause for the behaviour you observe. Maybe read this if you haven't: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/Website/projects/histogram256/doc/histogram.pdf

Comment: Yes the global memories are distinct. Why would the cache miss ratio correlate with the distance(x1, x2)? I don't really think so. Could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 3):

It's quite hard to calculate histograms in CUDA. I believe the random access on y[] may very well be the cause for the behaviour you observe. Maybe read this if you haven't: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/Website/projects/histogram256/doc/histogram.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I will read it. By the way, the access on y[] is quite regular, isn't it? And I just write on y[], not reading it at all. And I'm sorry I might not mention  in the question that all the misses are cache miss read.